# How can I target subset of objects in array and change a property to an incrementing number for each of those objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am struggling with a rather complicated operation on an array of objects.  First this is a sample array:

```
[
  {id: 11, item: 132, lineNum: 4, linePosition: 5}
  {id: 2, item: 124, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 2}
  {id: 9, item: 130, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 5}
  {id: 12, item: 133, lineNum: 1, linePosition: 3}
  {id: 15, item: 136, lineNum: 3, linePosition: 2}
  {id: 13, item: 134, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 4}
  {id: 10, item: 131, lineNum: 2, linePosition: 1}
  {id: 8, item: 129, lineNum: 3, linePosition: 3}
  {id: 1, item: 123, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 5}
  {id: 3, item: 125, lineNum: 1, linePosition: 7}
  {id: 5, item: 127, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 9}
  {id: 7, item: 128, lineNum: 1, linePosition: 2}
  {id: 4, item: 126, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 4}
  {id: 14, item: 135, lineNum: 3, linePosition: 9}
]
```

So I would like to do the following operations in order and as efficiently as possible.  Sort the array by lineNum then by item both ascending.  Then I would like to modify each object where `lineNum === 0` to make the linePosition an incrementing number starting at 0.  So the first matching object would have linePosition of 0, next would be 1, then 2, etc.

Resulting array would look like this:

```
[
  {id: 1, item: 123, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 0}
  {id: 2, item: 124, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 1}
  {id: 4, item: 126, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 2}
  {id: 5, item: 127, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 3}
  {id: 9, item: 130, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 4}
  {id: 13, item: 134, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 5}
  {id: 3, item: 125, lineNum: 1, linePosition: 7}
  {id: 7, item: 128, lineNum: 1, linePosition: 2}
  {id: 12, item: 133, lineNum: 1, linePosition: 3}
  {id: 10, item: 131, lineNum: 2, linePosition: 1}
  {id: 8, item: 129, lineNum: 3, linePosition: 3}
  {id: 14, item: 135, lineNum: 3, linePosition: 9}
  {id: 15, item: 136, lineNum: 3, linePosition: 2}
  {id: 11, item: 132, lineNum: 4, linePosition: 5}
]
```

Comment: Use `.sort()` to sort the array, then use a `.forEach()` loop to update the `linePosition` element. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I was hoping there would be a nice one liner using sort/filter/map etc.

Comment: `arr.sort((a, b) => a.lineNum === b.lineNum ? a.item - b.item : a.lineNum - b.lineNum).forEach((e, i) => e.linePosition = e.lineNum === 0 ? i : e.linePosition );` One liners are not always good))

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that is harder to read. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
let arr = getData();

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if( a.lineNum === b.lineNum ) {
    return a.item - b.item;
  } else {
    return a.lineNum - b.lineNum;
  }
});
// return a.lineNum === b.lineNum ? a.item - b.item : a.lineNum - b.lineNum;

for( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
  if( arr[i].lineNum > 0 ) break;
  arr[i].linePosition = i;
}
// Used classic loop, to break it and avoid unnecessary iterations.

console.log( JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/\},/g, "},\n") );

/***/
function getData() {
  return [
    {id: 11, item: 132, lineNum: 4, linePosition: 5},
    {id: 2, item: 124, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 2},
    {id: 9, item: 130, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 5},
    {id: 12, item: 133, lineNum: 1, linePosition: 3},
    {id: 15, item: 136, lineNum: 3, linePosition: 2},
    {id: 13, item: 134, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 4},
    {id: 10, item: 131, lineNum: 2, linePosition: 1},
    {id: 8, item: 129, lineNum: 3, linePosition: 3},
    {id: 1, item: 123, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 5},
    {id: 3, item: 125, lineNum: 1, linePosition: 7},
    {id: 5, item: 127, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 9},
    {id: 7, item: 128, lineNum: 1, linePosition: 2},
    {id: 4, item: 126, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 4},
    {id: 14, item: 135, lineNum: 3, linePosition: 9},
  ];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the mentioned task by using Javascript [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function. It can take a optional compare function parameter which specifies a function that defines the sort order.

```js
let arr = [
  {id: 11, item: 132, lineNum: 4, linePosition: 5},
  {id: 2, item: 124, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 2},
  {id: 9, item: 130, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 5},
  {id: 12, item: 133, lineNum: 1, linePosition: 3},
  {id: 15, item: 136, lineNum: 3, linePosition: 2},
  {id: 13, item: 134, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 4},
  {id: 10, item: 131, lineNum: 2, linePosition: 1},
  {id: 8, item: 129, lineNum: 3, linePosition: 3},
  {id: 1, item: 123, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 5},
  {id: 3, item: 125, lineNum: 1, linePosition: 7},
  {id: 5, item: 127, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 9},
  {id: 7, item: 128, lineNum: 1, linePosition: 2},
  {id: 4, item: 126, lineNum: 0, linePosition: 4},
  {id: 14, item: 135, lineNum: 3, linePosition: 9}
];

//sorting the given array, first based on lineNum, then by item
arr.sort(function(a,b){
  if(a.lineNum !== b.lineNum)
    return a.lineNum - b.lineNum;
  return a.item - b.item;
});

// modify each object where lineNum===0, linePosition starting from 0
// since we have sorted, break when first lineNum > 0
let linePos = 0;
for( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
  if( arr[i].lineNum > 0 ) 
    break;
  if(arr[i].lineNum === 0)
    arr[i].linePosition = linePos++;
}

//   console.log(arr); //<-- This prints as array

console.log( JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/\},/g, "},\n") ); // <-- This prints your mentioned format
```

Hope this helps !